# How to fetch all images from a folder in Firebase Storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on an story view application in which I've created a "stories" folder in firebase storage under which there is a folder with the "userID" and inside userID, I've stored all the stories of the respective user.

Now, I'm trying to fetch all those stories of the respective user. Here, is my function which I used to fetch the images but it gives me error "Image failed to load"

```
  String storyUrl = " ";
  void fetchstory() async {
  final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('stories');
    ref.listAll().then((value1) {
      value1.items.forEach((folder) {
        folder.listAll().then((value2) {
          value2.items.forEach((stories) {
            stories.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
              storyUrl = value;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add await and setState like this

```
await stories.getDownloadURL.then((value){setState({storyUrl = value;});});
```

Make sure to change stories data type to list because you wanna fetch all data not one story, like this

```
list<String> stories = "";
await stories.getDownloadURL.then((value){setState({storyUrl.add(value);});});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value should be a list of string since you are looping it

```dart
List<String> storyUrl = [];
  void fetchstory() async {
  final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('stories');
    ref.listAll().then((value1) {
      value1.items.forEach((folder) {
        folder.listAll().then((value2) {
          value2.items.forEach((stories) {
            stories.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
              storyUrl.add(value);//additems like this
              setState((){});
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Now, I want to display those Stories using their URL . For just testing I just pass URL as storyUrl[0] and storyUrl[1], but I get a RangeError (index) invalid value range is empty, Also, I have uploaded enough stories in the firebsae storage. Can you tell me why this is happening?